# Codesign returned 1 (object ifile format invalid or unsuitable) bug

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

I'm working with Xcode 4.1 build 4B110f trying to get my iOS app ready for upload.  It passes the Product|Archive step with no errors, asking twice for permission to sign something.  But when I try a validate of the archive from the Organizer, it fails:

```
### Codesigning '/Users/uqrchern/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/70D2381D-3733-4F5D-88B2-4729572C2864.mobileprovision' with 'iPhone Distribution: Ron Chernich'
+ /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata --sign iPhone Distribution: Ron Chernich --resource-rules=/var/folders/ul/ula1AHKnGpqQ9ftDnUL-l++++TM/-Tmp-/rybczU3EBd/Payload/ABRA-D.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /var/folders/ul/ula1AHKnGpqQ9ftDnUL-l++++TM/-Tmp-/rybczU3EBd/entitlements_plistrZ1Vwko6 /var/folders/ul/ula1AHKnGpqQ9ftDnUL-l++++TM/-Tmp-/rybczU3EBd/Payload/ABRA-D.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/var/folders/ul/ula1AHKnGpqQ9ftDnUL-l++++TM/-Tmp-/rybczU3EBd/Payload/ABRA-D.app: replacing existing signature
/var/folders/ul/ula1AHKnGpqQ9ftDnUL-l++++TM/-Tmp-/rybczU3EBd/Payload/ABRA-D.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
]
error: codesign failed with error 1
```

I've looked at all the similar problems and solutions (some of which make no sense whatever, or apply to really old versions of the tools).  None have made the slightest difference.

I've also checked 3 times that verify is using the "production" certificate, as is the codesign step that produces the archive.  I've even turned the above output into a schell script so I could try all certificates manually: same result every time.

Maybe the .app file being signed really is unsuitable?

Incidentally, codesign has no version flag, but the man page is dated June 1 2006.  The binary has a file date of Nov 20 2010.

**UPDATE (next day):**

Researching the problem further found an obscure reference saying that codesign needs the following environment var set:

```
CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
```

Using the output from a failed Validate run, I created a shell script which exported this var just before the failing codesign --force step and viola!  The codesign works.

But this does not really help me prepare my code for upload.  Is there a way to include this into the script run by the Organizer Validate button??

**A LITTLE LATER STILL, THE SOLUTION! :**

Under the theory there is a script someplace which generates all the commands run during an Organizer Validate... run, I did some digging with grep and find. The script indeed exists and it's name is:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication
```

It's just Perl and the fix is to add the required environment var to the associative array %ENV right at the start, say at line 72:

```
$ENV{CODESIGN_ALLOCATE} = '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate';
```

**This totally fixes the problem.** *I've no idea where all the other posters on the web who think they fixed it by combinations of deleting certificates, building clean, shutting down and restarting Xcode, etc, etc are coming from. I'll just quietly assert that this fix favors science over superstition and works for me under Xcode 4.1 Build 4B110f and its associated PackageApplication script, running under Snow Leopard 10.6.8 with Perl 5.10.0*

Comment: Saved my night man! I suspect that it has something to do with the beta of ios 5 (XCode 4.2) on my machine. Did you have only XCode 4.1 on your machine or also the 4.2?

Comment: You are right, I had the 4.2 beta installed previously and suspect that was the root of the problem as I didn't run the 4.2 uninstall before installing 4.1 (when I twigged and did run it, it failed to find several things because I'd renamed the 4.2 Developer dir prior to installing 4.1).

Comment: Thank you! You have saved me so much time and pain.

Comment: I'm so thankful to you. You've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

Just so that this can be taken off the unanswered list. Like you said, you need to add `CODESIGN_ALLOCATE` to the `$ENV` array:

```
$ENV{CODESIGN_ALLOCATE} = '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate';
```

If everyone is in agreement here, I think this question can finally be closed.

*When using a more recent version of Xcode, the default location is:*

```
$ENV{CODESIGN_ALLOCATE} = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate';
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue for building an OS X app in XCode 5. In that case, the path to set CODESIGN_ALLOCATE to is /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Comment: I'm on XCode 5.0.2 and can confirm that I needed to flip to the path CuriousKea specified.  I have successfully used all the previous paths with older versions of XCode, but 5.0.2 required yet another change.

Answer (score 1):

In case you get this on a recent version of Xcode, what you actually want is, in the shell:

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=`xcode-select -print-path`/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
```

which will use the codesign_allocate from the version of Xcode you are using.

You can update the version of Xcode the command line tools use by running xcode-select -switch

Answer (score 0):

I had this workaround in place for a long time, but after upgrading to Xcode 4.3 with iOS 5.1 SDK, my signing script (which calls `codesign`) stopped working with a `cannot find code object on disk` error:

```
output/Enterprise/Payload/MyProduct.app/MyProduct: replacing invalid existing signature    
output/Enterprise/Payload/MyProduct.app/MyProduct: cannot find code object on disk     
Code signing failed, not creating .ipa file
```

It seems this workaround isn't necessary for binaries built with Xcode 4.3.  To fix, I updated my bash script to check if the location exists before exporting it:

```
  # Only export the environment variable if the location exists,
  # otherwise it breaks the signing process!
  if [ -f "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate" ]
  then
    echo Export environment variable for codesign_allocate location
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
  fi
```