# Xcode building application to ipa from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, building

I'm unable to build ipa signed file from command line. First a few words about my environment:

**1. Application**
I've prepared a simple application for iPad from template "Master-Detail Application". Changed nothing in code, changed nothing in settings. Just plain new project.

**2. Build script**
Here is my build "script"

```
cd /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/

xcodebuild -target signtest -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.3 clean build

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/signtest.app -o /Users/admin/Desktop/binaries/signtest.ipa --sign "iPhone Developer: Marcin Zyga (CLJR93MXJ6)" --embed "/Users/admin/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1.mobileprovision"
```

**3. Problem**

Application is builded, and then I'm trying to make an ipa file from the build. But I've got this:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Packaging application: '/Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/signtest.app'
Arguments: embed=/Users/admin/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1.mobileprovision  verbose=1  output=/Users/admin/Desktop/binaries/signtest.ipa  sign=iPhone Developer: Marcin Zyga (CLJR93MXJ6)  
Environment variables:
HOME = /Users/admin
SUDO_GID = 20
DISPLAY = /tmp/launch-vj2zx7/org.x:0
VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT = no
MAIL = /var/mail/root
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/launch-YPyQMl/Listeners
PWD = /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest
LANG = pl_PL.UTF-8
USER = root
LOGNAME = root
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x0:29:42
USERNAME = root
SHLVL = 1
OLDPWD = /SMT/ci_shell_scripts
_ = /usr/bin/xcrun
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
LSCOLORS = GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
SUDO_USER = admin
SHELL = /bin/bash
TERM = xterm-256color
SUDO_COMMAND = ./sign_test_ipa.sh
VERSIONER_PERL_VERSION = 5.12
SUDO_UID = 502

Output directory: '/Users/admin/Desktop/binaries/signtest.ipa'
Temporary Directory: '/tmp/eiJTk08At3'  (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set)
+ /bin/cp -Rp /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/signtest.app /tmp/eiJTk08At3/Payload
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
### Checking original app
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/signtest.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/signtest.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
]
error: Codesign check fails : /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/signtest.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
```

The important part is here:

```
  Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/signtest.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
    ]
    error: Codesign check fails : /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/signtest.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
```

I'm unable to find solution.

**4. What I've already done**
Here is a list of what I've already tried to do. However if you are sure that things that I've already tried is solution for my problem please write step by step how to do this (maybe I've done something wrong earlier).

- [That codesign returned 1 (object ifile format invalid or unsuitable) problem again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425840/that-codesign-returned-1-object-ifile-format-invalid-or-unsuitable-problem-aga) - added propsed line of code, no effect at all
- [Xcode - Sharing app - PackageApplication failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138525/xcode-sharing-app-packageapplication-failed-with-exit-code-1) - setted in build settings Code Signing Resource Rules Path to $(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist
- [iPhone Codesign object file format invalid or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842717/iphone-codesign-object-file-format-invalid-or-unsuitable) - invoke commands

  sudo mv /usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin/codesign_allocate_old
  sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin

**5. What I'm trying to achive**
I'm trying to generate an ipa file signed with developer certificate so I can upload ipa file via iTunes to test it on device.

**6. Response to answers from below**

- I've changed the build command line to:

  xcodebuild -target signtest -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos clean build

But now I'm getting:

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET signtest OF PROJECT signtest WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1' can't be found


** BUILD FAILED **
```

I've manually setted provisioning profiles in xcode for this project. I've double checked and they are there. What I'm a doing wrong here? Moreover when I'm building with attached device it all goes fine and application start on my iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting the iPhone Simulator SDK in your build script.  Switch it to the real SDK.

Comment: Ok I've change build line to: xcodebuild -target signtest -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos clean build and now I'm getting: === BUILD NATIVE TARGET signtest OF PROJECT signtest WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1' can't be found


** BUILD FAILED ** I've checked the provisioning profile and it is there. I've configured project in Xcode to build with this profile. How I can configure this from command line?

Comment: Updated my question to reflect changes.

Comment: You have a different question now.  You shouldn't edit this question to change it to a different one, you should post a new question.

Comment: I do that and accept your answer as it seems it's correct one.